# Calculate lowest monthly payment using bisection search in python

Tags: python, bisection

I'm currently taking the MITx course on edx and I have a problem with one exercise. Can you please tell me why I get stuck in an infinite loop with this code? I guess the bisectional search loop isn't working properly but I don't really know why. Here's the code:

```
balance = 5000
annualInterestRate = 0.18
low = balance/12
high = (balance * (1 + annualInterestRate / 12) ** 12) / 12
guess = (low + high)/2

def getBal(guess, balance, annualInterestRate):
    mon = 0
    while mon < 12:
        mon += 1
        ub = balance - guess
        balance = ub + (annualInterestRate/12) * ub
    return balance

z = getBal(guess, balance, annualInterestRate)

while abs(round(z, 2)) > 0:
    if round(z, 2) > 0:
        low = guess
    else:
        high= guess
    guess = (high+low)/2

print "Lowest Payment: " + str(round(guess,2))
```

Comment: `while abs(round(z, 2)) > 0:` you never change the value of z to be non-positive

Comment: Ok, so the exercise is about finding the lowest monthly payment to pay off the entire credit card balance within a year. To do that we are supposed to use bisectional search. with the last while loop. And I thought by changing guess everytime the new value would go into the function which I assigned to the variable z...so I'm changing z, aren't I?

Comment: You aren't changing z. There is no line in the while loop that says `z = ` is there?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the while loop in getBal? You recalculate the same balance 12 times

Comment: True! I thought it would change automatically just my changing guess, but I had to write it in the statement of the while loop. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and the function works because it gets the balance at the end of the year by adding the interest for each month and subtracts the monthly payment based on my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the second loop.
You could try to do it this way:

```
balance = 5000
annual_interest_rate = 0.18
low = balance/12
high = (balance * (1 + annual_interest_rate / 12) ** 12) / 12
guess = (low + high)/2


def get_bal(g, b, air):
    mon = 0
    while mon < 12:
        mon += 1
        ub = b - g
        b = ub + (air/12) * ub
    return b

while True:
    z = get_bal(guess, balance, annual_interest_rate)
    if abs(round(z, 2)) == 0:
        break
    if round(z, 2) > 0:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (high+low)/2

print "Lowest Payment: " + str(round(guess, 2))
```

Comment: Because I was trying to change z with the new assignement of "guess". to get the right value of guess by checking if the balance I get from the function getBal equals 0

Comment: in this case you need to recalculate z in every cycle of the while loop, otherwise it's infinite loop, but it will not help because abs is always positive

Comment: If you get rid of the while loop, there is no bisection happening

Comment: Thank you!!! That thing about putting z in the loop helped. I just changed the loop statement.

Comment: The while-loop in `get_bal` doesn't need to exist unless the `b` value should be `-=` maybe?

Comment: @cricket_007 the question was about the infinite loop, i wasn't inclined to provide better algorithm, feel free to update my answer though, thanks